# How do I make an on/off switch for FK and IK limb rigs?

Tags: armature, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

I want to try and do the same thing rigify's rig system did and make a menu that allows me to switch between the IK and the FK limbs for my character's arms and legs. Right now, all I have is one simple IK limb for both arm and legs.[image]

Comment: Just type "blender ik fk switch" (without the quotes) into Google and you'll get a list of quick tutorials.

Comment: Note that Rigify's UI is a python script, you won't get exactly that with Blender without scripting.

Comment: Don't be afraid. The switch is just a driver, not that much Python script involved. Dikko has two series about this: [Beginners Guide to Rigging](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL3OEv6vd5VCrqZiupP2m68qSWHYAjoiW) / *part 4, Building the FK and IK Rig!* and [Character Rigging in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL3OEv6vd5VA8_FBkeitaeqC0kbcrhMTC) / *part 5, Creating a Robust Arm Rig*